# Получить прямой линк на песню Зайцев нет

Tags: php

Как получить прямую ссылку на трек на сайте зайцев.нет.

Пример страницы:
http://zaycev.net/search.html?query_search=%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0

Comment: Зайти на каждую страницу скачивания, найти не ней ссылку на скачивание, попробовать работает ли скачивание

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$res = file_get_contents('http://zaycev.net/search.html?query_search=%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0');

if (preg_match_all('#data-duration.*data-url="(.*)"#Usi', $res, $links, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {

    foreach ($links as $val) {
        $res = file_get_contents('http://zaycev.net' . $val[1]);
        $data = json_decode($res);
        echo $data->url . PHP_EOL;
    }
} else
    die(':(');

?>
```

Comment: Все отлично работает. Только не понял, что делает "$val[1]"? Поясните нубу пожалуйста.

Comment: @LEX в $val[1] хранится ссылка, пример: /musicset/play/e97190f30644a004bf4727b595ad5305/4328343.json
и не забудьте поставить галку слева от ответа, если ответ вам помог)